# Issues when trying to save variables from another text file using textscan() function

Tags: matlab

I am currently having issues with storing the values which I read from another text file using the textscan() function.

I am trying to use the NumPts as a counter so as to help me store the values of the number of variables from the dat file.

I am currently getting an error that states:
     Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
     Error in CorrectedWheelModelDataFromTxt (line 15) MyCellNumPts{1,1}= MyCellC{4,1};

Below is an excerpt of the code:

```
  MyCellXVal = cell(1,1000);
  MyCellYVal=  cell(1,1000);
  MyCellZVal=  cell(1,1000);
  MyCellNumPts = cell(1,1);
  NumPts=0;
  CountPts=1;

  MyCellC=cell(100,100);

  fileID = fopen('WheelReflectors.dat');
  MyCellC = textscan(fileID,'%d %d %d');
  fclose(fileID);

  MyCellNumPts{1,1}= MyCellC{4,1};
  NumPts = MyCellNumPts{1,1};
  while(CountPts<NumPts)

      MyCellXVal{1,CountPts} =C{CountPts,1};
      MyCellYVal{1,CountPts} =C{CountPts,2};
      MyCellZVal{1,CountPts} =C{CountPts,3};

      CountPts = CountPts +1;
  end
```

Below contains the data of the dat file:
   130 40 70
   270 40 70
   200 40 0
   3

I don't understand why I am getting the matrix dimension issue when I am just trying to store one value. Please advise me. Appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dbstop if error` to check what is happening, but basically:

First you create a 100 x 100 empty cell:

```
  `MyCellC=cell(100,100);`
```

But when you call `textscan` that is entirely overwritten.

```
  fileID = fopen('WheelReflectors.dat');
  MyCellC = textscan(fileID,'%d %d %d');
  fclose(fileID);
```

MyCellC is now size 1 x 3, and therefore you cannot access MyCellC{4,1} in the following line:

```
  MyCellNumPts{1,1}= MyCellC{4,1};
```

(It's not clear which number you want there, maybe `myCellC{1}(4)`?)

My suggestion: run up to `fclose(fileID);` from the command line, and then look at `MyCellC` and make sure you understand how the data is being organised as it is read in.  You do not need any sort of loop here.